# TWebBrowser local web pages have stopped working in Delphi 11 ( Alexandria )

Tags: delphi, mobile, firemonkey, twebbrowser

Local file URLs have stopped working for the TwebBrowser component under Android32 bit applications when going from Delphi 10.4 to Delphi 11. I use TWebBrowser to deliver embedded help pages in my mobile app. The same code worked with with previous versions of Delphi.

Specifically urls that start with the file://data/user

The URLs are being parsed incorrectly so the path part throws away the /data bit.

Comment: Sounds like a bug/regression that you should [report to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: Okay I reported it as a bug to Embarcadero.